# How to convert my partial In Memory LINQ GroupBy query to complete Database Query or should I use raw sql?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I tried different ways to solve this but either it wont let me include or it gives error for the GroupBy statement.

In the above code, I am trying to Group the MedicineEquipments by FOREIGN KEY i.e LocationId, and take the latest record with that LocationId and also include Location and MedicineEquipmentNavigation along with the record.

```
var medicineEquipmentShops = await dbContext.MedicineEquipments
                                    .Where(x => x.CityId == cityId  && x.MedicineEquipmentId == medicineEquippmentId)
                                    .Include(x => x.Location)
                                    .Include(x =>x.MedicineEquipmentNavigation)
                                    .ToListAsync();
medicineEquipmentShops = medicineEquipmentShops.GroupBy(x => x.LocationId)
                                        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.UpdatedOn).FirstOrDefault())
                                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.IsVerified)
                                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.Stock)
                                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.Votes)
                                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you tell us the error you get with the GroupBy call?

Comment: @Chris The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: m.LocationId, 
ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: MedicineEquipment
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False

    .OrderByDescending(y => y.UpdatedOn)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.